# Simplest way to animate images in c# windows application

Tags: c#, image, animation, slideshow, windows

I have a windows application that preview list of images before being published to a web server, without the usage of WPF I need to animate (swipe or fade in fade out or flipping) between pictures when the user presses next or previous

Thanks
Hamza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could animate images using the `ImageAnimator` Class

**Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Windows.Forms;

public class animateImage : Form 
{

    //Create a Bitmpap Object.
    Bitmap animatedImage = new Bitmap("SampleAnimation.gif");
    bool currentlyAnimating = false;

    //This method begins the animation.
    public void AnimateImage() 
    {
        if (!currentlyAnimating) 
        {

            //Begin the animation only once.
            ImageAnimator.Animate(animatedImage, new EventHandler(this.OnFrameChanged));
            currentlyAnimating = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnFrameChanged(object o, EventArgs e) 
    {

        //Force a call to the Paint event handler.
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
    {

        //Begin the animation.
        AnimateImage();

        //Get the next frame ready for rendering.
        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();

        //Draw the next frame in the animation.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.animatedImage, new Point(0, 0));
    }
```